# Ubuntu does not recognize my built-in monitor

Tags: 10.10, boot, monitor

I've recently discovered of a boot problem Ubuntu has with my laptop. I have successfully installed Ubuntu on two other computers, and I've never experienced this problem. What happens is, after the live boot CD loads, the screen goes completely blank. Although, I suspected that there was no problem booting, so I loaded with BIOS only, which worked perfectly fine. Of course, not being very proficient with this, I have no idea what needs to be done to fix the problem.

I have switchable graphics cards(the ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650, and some low-end Intel card), and an Intel i5 quad core processor. I was booting with the Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit desktop distribution. If there's any more information you need from me, please let me know.

EDIT: I was able to look into this a bit more, thanks to one of the comments provided, and I have some new information. Ubuntu does seem to be able to recognize both of my graphics cards. The problem I found was that, in the Xorg.0 log, it mentions that there were "no screens found." I'm using a notebook, so the screen is built in. Does anyone know of a way to get Ubuntu to recognize the monitor?

Comment: We need more information to help you, can you look at this question and then edit your question adding more detail? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Can you add what model laptop you have please?

Comment: @B3tturTh3nU [More information here](http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages#Ikeepgettingthemessage.3A.22noscreensfound.22) on what the "no screens found" error means. What other messages are in your log?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try totally removing one of your cards, or disabling the build in if exists from your bios. When you see the picture of the keybord = a picture of a guy in the beggining press any key and try to load any available modules for your relevant graphic card (my wild guess is that one of them will work with the standar installation) to continue the boot process. An output or a more detailed description would be helpful.